Question about visualising edge gluing in topology
I am reading through a text called “Perspectives on Projective Geometry” and a proof method they presented entailed the following gluing scheme (Fig 15.14, pg 289):

Here they glue the opposite edges only in the image on the far left (so you are left with three vertices).
I understand that you are left with three vertices, but not sure how they get the configuration in the middle, or how I am supposed to think about what happens to the middle points.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

can you explain what the three vertices are?  And by "middle points" do you mean what the author calls "edge points" ?

@brainjam I figured out in chapter 15. Basically, I realize, given a pappus configuration you can generate triangles with Ceva and glue them together to get a configuration shown above (a torus). Going in the other direction, we glue as above and we get the configuration shown (I wasn't visualizing gluing properly, it is easier to imagine pinching two vertex at a time, and seeing the lines on the surface).
